# JPA Select from a view

Tags: mysql, jpa, view

I try to select entities from a view defined in MySQL and I always get an error `item_to_process is not mapped`

How to avoid that?

I declare the view directly in MySQL and then try to get result with this code in my repository:

```
    @Query("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE id IN (SELECT item_id FROM item_to_process)")
    List<Item> findItemToProcess();
```

Comment: That is a JPQL query. JPQL is not SQL. It doesn't use table, view and column names. Never. Always entity names and their persistence properties. You're basically doing the equivalent of trying to use C++ syntax in a Java program. Those are different languages.

Comment: Yes I was aware of that but is there a way to map JPQL and SQL ?

Comment: Again, JPQL works with entities. So if you want to access a view using JPQL, the view needs to be mapped by an entity. Use SQL if you don't want that, not JPQL. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#nativeQuery--

Comment: Is there a way to declare SQL views in JPQL?  or something like that..

Comment: No. As I said, JPQL works with entities. Always. Never view, tables and column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new entity and map it to database view. Use that entity in JPQL.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this but I ended doing it because it seems to be the only one...